# iOS WebRTC is not working with some STUN/TURN servers

Tags: ios, swift, video, webrtc, voip

We have a platform that has the Dashboard, Android app and the iOS app and it is using webRTC for video calls.The problem is Android and Dashboard are working ok with all of our STUN/TURN servers, but iOS is working with a few of them. to describe it in more detail when I use "turn:numb.viagenie.ca" and "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" together in the iOS app, it almost works on every different networks, except for protected wifi's on port 433 and 80. since we had a problem on webrtc connection being made on protected wifi's with the mentioned ports on all of our platforms, we have created some extra ICE servers just for those ports. the problem is that those servers are working fine with android and dashboard, but not with iOS. when I added those ICE servers to the iOS app it gets stuck at checking for finding matching candidates. anyone has any Idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using coturn or restund and test different ports I guess.. I am currently facing the same issue with iOS and am doing the same. Please update any success

Comment: I've tried everything so far and none of them worked. if you found anything too please let me know

Comment: "bump!" Same here.